# Did the School Authorities never find the the Burned One with the Ring

Tags: the-winx-saga

In the Neflix version of the Fate: The Winx Saga, the two plot lines of Episode 2 "No Strangers Here" revolve around the retrieval of Stella's ring from the Burned One chained in a cabin in the woods and the attack on Silva's troupe of soldiers on the way to move it to a more secure location.

The climax of the ring plot line is the impaling of the Burned on on a Tree branch by Aisha.

Sliva's thread continues into Episode 3, where the Burned One that infected him is being tracked as it's death is the only way to remove the magical infection. It is successfully tracked and killed but Silva doesn't get better leading the Teacher trio to believe a "second" burned one is out there.

Do they not know about the original Burned One impaled on the tree root? Did no one look for it? Or find out more about what Terra and Musa were doing in the forest when they rescued Silva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They didn't know about the Burned One impaled in the tree by Aisha.**

That's why the teachers were shocked when they discover that killing the Burned One that was being tracked didn't heal Silva, implying there's more than a single Burned One, as they initially thought (or hoped).

For example, in the [S1E03 32:20](https://www.netflix.com/watch/81099370?t=1940), Silva says:

> -The one they killed musntn't have been the one that attacked me.
> -Clearly, there are more than one of the creatures out there

As if he just discovered that there were more than one. A little later, in the [33:20](https://www.netflix.com/watch/81099370?t=1995), the Headmistress says:

> -Got it wrong
> -I so wanted to believe it was a one-off...

Both scenes clearly imply that they didn't know about the Burned One in the forest that was killed by Aisha in S1E02. Thus, we can conclude that the teachers never bothered to ask to the Winx girls what were they doing in the forest.

Comment: These are the exact scenes that made me ask the question. And it agrees with everything else I've seen. I hoping someone else noticed something, but have a +1 for getting the timestamps and quotes, it's a massive improvement.